# Как обнаружить изменение значения tkinter.Spinbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

В GUI программы есть элемент, которым пользователь задаёт целое значение. На экране он выглядит так:

[image: Задаём целое, с помощью Spinbox]

В программе это реализовано так:

```
class StepNum(Frame):
    """
    Виджет, отображающий номер шага тестирования и позволяющий
    изменять значение этого номера.
    Содержит виджеты:

    * Label - Подпись
    * Spinbox - Значение
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, stepList):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI(stepList)

    def initUI(self, stepList):

        Label(self, text="Шаг №").grid(row=0, column=0, 
                                       padx=3, sticky='w')
        self.sp = Spinbox(self, values=stepList, command=self.spinClicket)
        self.sp.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=3, sticky='w')

    def spinClicket(self):
        new_step_num = self.sp.get()
        print("Новое значение: {0}".format(new_step_num))
```

Если пользователь щёлкает по стрелочкам спин-бокса, то вызывается функция *spinClicket* и печатается новое значение.

Однако!!! Если пользователь вводит новое значение непосредственно с клавиатуры в поле редактирования *Spinbox*, то ничего не происходит и функция *spinClicket* не вызывается.

Как перехватить такой *прямой* ввод в спин?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать `StringVar`

```
import tkinter


def func(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    print("Новое значение: {0}".format(myvar.get()))


root = tkinter.Tk()
myvar = tkinter.StringVar()
myvar.set('')
mywidget = tkinter.Spinbox(root, textvariable=myvar, width=10, command=func)
mywidget.pack()

mywidget.update_idletasks()

myvar.trace('w', func)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что хотелось бы, но можно и так попробовать.  Я когда на Qt писал, там было такое событие, типа "ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ редактирования текстового поля". А в таком варианте ф-ция вызывается каждый раз, при нажатии клавиши. Придётся что-то придумывать дополнительно.